# Calculating acceleration based on an angle

Tags: algorithm, math, vector

For a project I'm working on using a game API, I am attempting to create a rollercoaster. This rollercoaster uses 3 dimensional vectors to tell the cart where to go.

I use a variable (I) to tell the cart which point to go to, for example I = 1 would mean the cart moves to point one on the rails. I can increment I until the end of the array of vectors, which moves it along the track like a real rollercoaster cart.

As you may have thought, this would mean the cart's movement is linear and it would not accelerate according to the angle of the rails.

I want to find an algorithm to calculate which rail the cart should move to, based off of the angle the cart is currently on and what acceleration it should have. I hope the images below should explain this better.

Explanation 1

[image: Explanation 1]

Explanation 2

[image: Explanation 2]

Comment: Not a good idea posting links to images

Comment: @EdHeal StackOverflow has excellent image embedding support for a reason: if an image helps the post, it's a great idea.

Comment: I said links to images

Comment: @EdHeal sorry about that, seems a moderator has fixed it for me.

Comment: @EdHeal You might have forgotten, but low-rep users are not allowed to post images directly; they can only post links.

Comment: Realistic physical simulation of a mass moving on a track - which is what you want - is not super hard, but imo too big a topic for a SO post. You'll end up with a simple differential equation with respect to t, and your program will  need to implement a solver. This is covered well by books on game physics.  Suggest you get one and start reading. My personal fav: https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=ynQZBwAAQBAJ&source=productsearch&utm_source=HA_Desktop_US&utm_medium=SEM&utm_campaign=PLA&pcampaignid=MKTAD0930BO1&gl=US&gclid=CNGKx9bY0M4CFYPr6QodKPcErA&gclsrc=ds

Comment: @Gene Would this be something that uses a lot of processing power? The API I am using has maximum quotas, and they aren't at all generous. Thanks. (also, solver?)

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively straight forward mechanics, which is covered in A level maths.

In free fall the acceleration due to gravity is 10 m s^-2 and use F=m a we can calculate the force due to gravity which we will call G.

Now if you are on a sloping track there is a reaction force perpendicular to the track. This balances out the component of gravity in that direction, basically meaning the cart does not fall through the track. There is another component of gravity parallel to the track. This component will give the acceleration/deceleration.

Now if the track is at angle theta to the horizontal the two components will be

```
  G cos(theta)            perpendicular to the track
  G sin(theta)            parallel to the track
```

The second of these is the interesting one. Giving the acceleration as 
10 sin(theta), in the direction along the track.

```
 \
  \
   \       ^ R
    \     /
     \   /
      \ /
      |\
      | \
      |  \
    G V   \
           \
```

The two forces acting on the cart.

```
 \
  \
   \       
    \     
     \   
      \ \
       \ \
        \ V
         \  G sin(theta)
          \
           \
```

The resulting force.

Now we know the acceleration we can use the [Equations of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Kinematic_quantities) to calculate the position after time t. The formula we want is

r = r0 + v t + 0.5 a t^2

where r0 is the initial position, v is the initial velocity, a is the acceleration and t is the time elapsed. As your track is curved it will be better to use many small steps for t, calculating the acceleration at each and ensuring the velocity is along the track.

If you want to consider your track as piece-wise linear. You can calculate the time taken to move from the start of one segment to the next.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am wondering how I would determine whether the cart should accelerate or decelerate with my system. If a single rail was completely vertical, it could be either going up, or going down. Sorry if I missed something... I just program for a hobby and am probably not old enough to fully understand this stuff.

Comment: The acceleration will always be downward. If the cart is moving up hill then the net result will be a deceleration.